# yum sort available packages by one of attributes

Tags: linux, unix, yum

How can I sort available packages by one of info attributes, for examample, by size?

I can use

```
yum info list *wildcard_seach_for_pkg_name*
```

But how can I sort result of this command by info's attribute or output only size from info?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that, to sort, you'll have to work some scripting magic: perhaps python or whatever language suits you.  I believe you'll have to use that approach because the manual page (at least for yum on CentOS 7.2) does not mention anything about sorting options to `info`.  It does say that `info` takes the same options as `list` and none of them have anything to do with sorting.

As for printing just the size, there's probably lots of ways for doing **just that.**  One way is with awk.  Here is an example:

```
yum info "kernel*" | awk -e '/^Size/ { print $1, "-->", $3, $4 }'
```

which produced

```
Size --> 136 M
Size --> 136 M
Size --> 136 M
Size --> 136 M
Size --> 136 M
...
```